# Login en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, login

Estoy implementando en mi app android un login tanto con usuario y con password como con google y todo esto con firebase. El caso es que tengo dos botones, un botón que me inicia sesión cogiendo los datos Email y Password de dos editText y otro botón que me loguea con google. He seguido todos los pasos que vienen en la documentación y todo correcto. El problema lo tengo cuando al iniciar sesión utilizando el botón de email and pass, también se ejecuta el código referente al de google y me inicia sesión dos veces, una con el email y la pass y otra con google y no entiendo por que. Os dejo el código por si me podéis ayudar:

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;


private SignInButton btnInicioSesionGoogle;
private EditText edtEmail , edtPass;
private Button btnInicioSesion;
private TextView txtRegistro;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container
        , Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio_sesion
            ,container , false);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    edtEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    edtPass = view.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

    btnInicioSesion = view.findViewById(R.id.btnInicioSesion);
    btnInicioSesion.setOnClickListener(this);


    //////////////GOOGLE///////////////////////////////////////////

    btnInicioSesionGoogle = view.findViewById(R.id.btnInicioSesionGoogle);
    btnInicioSesionGoogle.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

public void iniciarSesionCorreoYPass(){

    final String email = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = edtPass.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Introduce su correo electronico",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Introduce contraseña",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage("Iniciando Sesion");
    progressDialog.show();

    //Login

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email , password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                FirebaseUser usuario = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hola de nuevo: "+usuario.getEmail() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DrawerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if(task.isCanceled())
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR. Datos Incorrectos" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
}

//Google
private void iniciarSesionGoogle() {

    if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestEmail().build();
    //GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();

    final Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

        try {
            //final GoogleApiClient client = mGoogleApiClient;

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);

        }


    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GOOOOOOGLEEEEEEE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DrawerActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnInicioSesion:
            iniciarSesionCorreoYPass();
        case R.id.btnInicioSesionGoogle:
            iniciarSesionGoogle();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Espero que podáis ayudarme, un saludo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta un break en el primer case, y es por lo que te entra luego en el segundo.

Ponlo así:

```
switch (v.getId())
{
    case R.id.btnInicioSesion:
        iniciarSesionCorreoYPass();
        break;
    case R.id.btnInicioSesionGoogle:
        iniciarSesionGoogle();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso lo que ocurría menuda cagada jejeje

Comment: Suele pasar que nos empeñamos en todo lo complejo y se nos olvida revisar lo más sencillo. xD